# Reactjs: Form action method and onSubmit

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I have a situation where I need to submit my form.
When I use this method 1

`Method 1`

```
<form action="my_redirect_url" method="post" onSubmit={this.registerEmail.bind(this)}>
   <input
     type="text"
     placeholder='Email address'
     name='EMAIL'
     value={this.state.email}
     onChange={this.handleChangeEmail}
   />
   <button type='submit' />
</form>
```

Then the form submits perfectly but I miss the form validation i.e the email validation part. Its valid or not, the form redirects

`Method 2`

```
// onSubmit method
registerEmail = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let { email } = this.state;
  let emailValidated = validateEmail(email);
  if (emailValidated) {
    fetch('my_redirect_url', {
      method: 'post',
      body : JSON.stringify({
        EMAIL: email
      }),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(ParseJSON) // It parses the output
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("error---", error)
    });
  } else {
    alert("invalid email")
  }
}

// Form
<form onSubmit={this.registerEmail.bind(this)}>
   <input
     type="text"
     placeholder='Email address'
     name='EMAIL'
     value={this.state.email}
     onChange={this.handleChangeEmail}
   />
   <button type='submit' />
</form>
```

In Method 2, the validation is done correctly but then it doesnot redirects and says an error that `Fetch api cannot load 'my_redirect_url' Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)`

So whats the issue and how can it be solved?

Comment: You are missing `then` part of the fetch API. `fetch` has no idea what to deal with response object.

Comment: I'll modify the code. I have the `.then` part as well

Comment: @iamsaksham is the API belong to the same sever or else?

Comment: As the error says, the server failed to compy with your preflight request. Are you serving this file via the file protocol of your browser: e.g.: `file:///path/to/my/file.html`?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN its a different domain, so i think different server.

Comment: @DánielEmődKovács I am using express to serve the file. I'm working on `localhost:3000` and the `my_redirect_url is https://xyz/abc.php`

Comment: I think I got the issue. Its with mailchimp not working with fetch request. Finding for its answer now

Comment: This is intended behaviour. From one domain your are hitting a cross domain via the client side directly.

Comment: @NitishPhanse so how is it to be tackeled?

Comment: You can use `e.preventDefault()` if email isn't validated in method 2. If validated, let script run without `fetch`.

Comment: @iamsaksham there are 2 ways you can tackle this
1. On `https://xyz/abc.php` enable CORS headers for incoming requests, and add CORS headers in the request you are sending from the fetch api. 
2. Add an nginx or server redirect which will pass all requests with a sub route to `https://xyz/abc.php`. For eg From the browser you will hit `localhost:3000/my_api` and then nginx will redirect all /my_api requests to  `https://xyz/abc.php`. This way from you client you are hitting its own domain
Id suggest the second one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you tell the program to `e.preventDefault()`, then he won't execute the normal redirect, which we are all waiting for.

So vice versa you have to remove it to redirect the user afterward. Only `preventDefault()` if the E-Mail is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, but then its missing the validation part. Also it just adds query params to the url and redirects to that. But I want it to redirect to whole new domain

Comment: then do `window.location = 'www.google.com'` inside the `.then()` operation

Comment: but its not going in then, it says an error. I mentioned in the question. But yeah, I'll try what u say

Comment: I think u've solved it partially. Now I just need why is it going in `catch` part, rather than the `.then()`

Comment: The error means that the URL you're hitting is responding with a redirect to another URL, which isn`t really useful for fetch.

Comment: So whats the correct way for this?? I mean how to do it instead of using fetch?

Comment: That's nothing I can solve for you have to build up your website/webservice correctly. So don't redirect 301 the user but sending him a page success with a 400 response!

Comment: @iamsaksham if this solved your problem feel free to tag it as solved, I'm going to change the solution.